# Excel 2010 VBA CommandButton Unrecognized

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button (cmdbConMasterList) on sheet 1 of my workbook.  In a userform I attempt to change the fore and back colors of the button:

```
cmdbConMasterList.BackColor = &HFF& 
cmdbConMasterList.ForeColor = &HFFFF&
```

I get "Compile Error: Variable Not Defined".  I checked and rechecked the button name--no go.  It appears that the button name is not recognized across the whole application.  What's the remedy?

Comment: `Sheet1.cmdbConMasterList.BackColor = &HFF& `

Comment: you don't need the `&` at the end. `Color = &HFF` or `Color = rgbRed`

Comment: Where is your button?  sheet1 or userform1?

Answer (score 0):

Command Buttons on a Worksheet is different to UserForms. AFAIK, you cannot change their Fore and Back Colors, Font related only.

```
With Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Buttons("cmdbConMasterList").Font
    .Color = RGB(255,0,0)
    .Name = "Consolas"
    .Bold = True
    .Size = 18
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

## ActiveX control Button build in worksheet (not userform)

Try the codes below.

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Object
        .BackColor = &HFF
        .ForeColor = &HFFFFFF
    End With
End Sub
```